# Azure Event Hubs integration with Apache Spark in Python

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks

I would like to know if there are something [like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-spark-connector) this in python?

If so, could you provided any web with examples?

EXTRA:

If you are trying to run it like a normal python program it will give you an error:

Run it using:

```
spark-submit --packages com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.9 nameoffile.py
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/structured-streaming-python.html

https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md

```
# Source with default settings
connectionString = "YOUR.CONNECTION.STRING"
ehConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString' : connectionString
}

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()
```

Comment: Believe me when I ask something I try to look for it before.The web you posted is the same I saw before and that is not what I asking/looking for. In the title of the post I talk about Integrating Apache Spark with Azure Event Hubs. I saw that with scala but not with python.So I would like to know about any python connector to work like this org.apache.spark.eventhubs

Comment: I've updated accordingly. Apologies I thought the original mentioned event hub as well.

Comment: Thanks @HaukeMallow